# How should I create a grid view in polymer?

Tags: polymer, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a grid like a view like this [image]  using polymer
how should i approach this,there are lot of things I am getting confused, which would be the best way to approach this type of design whether  bootstrap with polymer or any web components, so that it can be customized  and how should I use it, any link or reference would be of great help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `iron-flex-layout` component that provide simple ways to use CSS flexible box layout or `flexbox`. Check out the guides from [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout). This component also provides two different ways to use `flexbox`:

- **Layout classes**. The layout class stylesheet provides a simple set of class-based flexbox rules. Layout classes let you specify layout properties directly in markup.
- **Custom CSS mixins**. The mixin stylesheet includes custom CSS mixins that can be applied inside a CSS rule using the `@apply` function.

Check the [demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jdd8X4t4gDoXUXRfM9Oj?p=preview).

Comment: can i exclude the flex container and use only flex item?

Comment: You have to use flex container so that it enables a flex context for all its direct children.

Comment: i have to include a watermark image in body,will the flexbox container will let me do so?

Comment: A `flex container` is just an element(e.g. div) with its `display` property set to either `flex` (rendered as a block) or `inline-flex` (rendered as inline). You can include anything in the body.

Comment: @shashank Did you try my solution?

Comment: i am using your solution

Comment: i am using your solution but i am not able to get the alignment of boxes can you please have a look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998037/iron-flex-layout-not-getting-the-proper-layout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153452/discussion-between-shashank-and-ofisora).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use css grid layout.  A good summary is  at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 0):

A search fro grid in the components catalog will give  a list of grid elements you can use

[Polymer Catalog (grid)](https://www.webcomponents.org/search/grid)

or you can use the `iron-flex` element 
[iron-flex](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout)

Answer (score 0):

App-grid could also help you: 
https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-layout/elements/app-grid