# Iron flex layout: not getting the proper layout

Tags: css, flexbox, polymer-1.0

i am using iron flex layout https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout i wanted to align my div like a dashboard view 
 but i am not able to align the boxes, i am using the layout standards https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout/blob/master/iron-flex-layout-classes.html mentioned here, no other iron flex styling is working other than layout inline layout-start

The template look likes

```
 </custom-style>
 <style>

    .layout {
     background-color: #263367;
     padding: 12px;
     margin: 4px;
     height: 300px;
   }
   .layout.center-justified{
     background-color: #289378;
     padding: 12px;
     margin: 4px;
     height: 100px;

 }

   </style>

   <div class="layout inline layout-center-justified" style="height: 154px">
      <div>cross axis start alignment</div>
     </div>

   <div class="layout inline layout-start" style="height: 74px width:24px">
     <div>cross axis start alignment</div>
   </div>

    <div class="layout inline layout-start" style="height: 154px">
   <div>cross axis start alignment</div>
   </div>

  <div class="layout inline layout-start" style="height: 154px">
  <div>cross axis start alignment</div>
 </div>

  <div class="layout inline layout-start" style="height: 154px">
     <div>cross axis start alignment</div>
  </div>
```

The div is not showing when i am using layout inline layout-center-justified

```
 <div class="layout inline layout-center-justified" style="height: 154px">
      <div>cross axis start alignment</div>
     </div>
```

can anyone guide me how should i style the below boxes 
so that it can come according to my requirment and how should i use https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout/blob/master/iron-flex-layout-classes.html so that i can use other layout classes?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `iron-flex-layout` make sure you read this guide: https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout.

To use layout classes import the `iron-flex-layout-classes` file. You must do the followings in any element that uses any of the `iron-flex-layout` styles:

- Import the file

  `<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">`
- Include the modules in `style`

  ```
  <style include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment">
  ```

If you want to learn basics about CSS `flexbox`, [click here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

For you problem you will need at least one flex container.

Here is the updated code using flex container:

```
<template>
    <style include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment">

      .inline {
        background-color: #263367;
        padding: 12px;
        margin: 4px;
        /*height: 300px;*/
        border: 1px solid black;

      }

      .layout-center-justified {
        background-color: #289378;
        padding: 12px;
        margin: 4px;
        /*height: 100px;*/
      }
    </style>


    <div class="vertical layout">
      <div class="horizontal layout justified">
        <div class="layout inline layout-center-justified" style="height: 154px">
          <div>cross axis start alignment</div>
        </div>

        <div class="layout flex inline layout-start" style="height: 74px width:24px">
          <div>cross axis start alignment</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="horizontal layout justified">
        <div class="layout inline layout-start" style="height: 154px">
          <div>cross axis start alignment</div>
        </div>

        <div class="layout inline layout-start" style="height: 154px">
          <div>cross axis start alignment</div>
        </div>

        <div class="layout inline layout-start" style="height: 154px">
          <div>cross axis start alignment</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Check out the [demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3aVileYvxi4mdMnjw6DJ?p=preview).

Comment: i was trying to modify the layout so that it can be aligned according to above image i have edited the image, i used flex-stretch but i am not able to stretch the right upper box to down ,can you please check it once https://plnkr.co/edit/nu8jQhQrvsc4KnHGmcCN?p=preview&lipi=urn:li:page:d_flagship3_messaging%3BcncZixtJSnWqdyZBVZ%2B8kg%3D%3D

Comment: i have almost got there  https://plnkr.co/edit/nu8jQhQrvsc4KnHGmcCN?p=preview&lipi=urn:li:page:d_flagship3_messaging%3BcncZixtJSnWqdyZBVZ%2B8kg%3D%3D but there is lot space between left boxes and right box

Comment: You are using `class='flex'` for both child so they are sharing equal spaces. In your case, you can use it for only one class or don't use it. Try removing that and see the changes.

Comment: I have removed the class flex but it if i stretch the screen the left boxes are getting stretched , but i want the righ boxes to be stretched   https://plnkr.co/edit/nu8jQhQrvsc4KnHGmcCN?p=preview&lipi=urn:li:page:d_flagship3_messaging%3BcncZixtJSnWqdyZBVZ%2B8kg%3D%3D

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/o5deyHxGrpRV8jBhK4je?p=preview&lipi=urn:li:page:d_flagship3_messaging%3BcncZixtJSnWqdyZBVZ%2B8kg%3D%3D

Comment: Did you check the link above?

Comment: Yeah i checked the link it's what i wanted but the flex layout are not soresponsive